# canvas background image only displays from netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

My project contains a canvas. I display a background image on the canvas.
When I run the program from netbeans, the background image displays. When I run the jar file, it does not. 
I looked at the jar file and I see the image folder and file.
I tried to create a resource folder, however I don't know how to do it and all my attempts failed.

I would like to have the program work without creating a folder just for the background.
All of my button images come from the same folder. They all display fine.

Also, I tried using a buffered image ImageIO.read(fName), but that ddes the same as getImage.

How do I get the getImage() to find the file in production?
A

```
Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
bi=t.getImage("src/images/Image.jpg");   // only from netbeans

bi=t.getImage("c:/images/Image.jpg");    // always works

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g.drawImage(bi, 5, 0, this);  // background
```

}

Comment: Don't include drive letters. Your drive is not available to the jar file. You should be loading images as resource. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Loading Images as Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource).

Comment: The drive letter did work, however that is NOT what I want. Reading the Swing tutorial on Resources, helped. It is now working using resources. Thanks.

Comment: @GaryK4 Since you have found a solution to your problem, could you consider posting that as an answer to your own question? That would be helpful to the SO community.